# misunderstand of angular installing as beginner

Tags: angular, angular-components

I'm a beginner in Angular 2

I tried to install Angular 2 and followed steps from angular.io  using quickstart

In the tutorials I watched in app-component file I noticed that the first line was

including components from angular2/core

```
import {Component} from "@angular2/core";
```

in my install I noticed that line in the same file is

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
```

the question is :

Are the two lines are the same or did I do something wrong in installing?

Comment: `@angular2` is the old package's name. They changed it to `@angular`.

Comment: If you are new to angular, I recommend you to do the [Angular-CLI Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cli-quickstart.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks Ploppy i got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing `@angular2/core`. it must be `angular2/core`

When angular2 was in beta version (before Beta 17), angular2 was used `angular2/core` way but later its moved to @angular namespace and came like `@angular/core`

Now all the angular packages and libraries are under @angular namespace

```
@angular/core
@angular/common
@angular/compailer
```

So if you see `angular2/core` consider it as before beta 17 release of angular or not official angular (as code pen pluner used that to make cdn use)and consider to update to angular 4 which will show `@angular/core`

Also `angular-cli` is moved to `@angular/cli` and by default generates angular 4 code.

Comment: thanks Aniruddha Das
I got it

Comment: @MustafaAgamey can you accept and upvote the answer plz

Comment: low reputation I'm sorry

Comment: I think with low reputation you can accept answer by clicking the tick mark  up and dow arrow